# React native Android Home always starts a splash screen

Tags: react-native

Using navigator I hit home from my react native android app and then return to the app and it always starts at the initial route which is my splash screen. Is there away to keep the component that was in view last the component that will be in view when the app re-opens?

```
class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
            style={{ flex:1 }}
             initialRoute={{ id: 'SplashPage' }}
             renderScene={ this.renderScene }
      />
    );
  }
    renderScene(route, navigator) {
      if (route.id === 'SplashPage') {
        return (
          <SplashPage
            navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}
             />
        );
      }else if(route.id === 'HomePage'){
        return (
          <HomePage
            navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}
             />
        );
      }else if(route.id === 'ListViewPage'){
        return (
          <ListViewPage
            navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}
             />
        );
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you make it more clear? i don't get your question.

Comment: What I want to happen is that whatever page my app was on before I hit the Android Home button, then when I open my app again then I return to that page and not my initial route.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to /android/app/src/main/java/com//MainActivity.java. so, that it maintains the stacks of application.

```
     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
       if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
          mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
        } else {
          super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

if you dont achieve your answer from above please follow reference as below:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

and in last of above reference there is lifecycle event for application in react-native. So, follow same strategy like native android onPause/onDestroy/onStop method and please solve your problem.

Comment: What I want to happen is that whatever page my app was on before I hit the Android Home button, then when I open my app again then I return to that page and not my initial route.

Comment: first you need to know that you are talking about lifecycle of android app, when you press home button your application goes in onPause state of activity and when you reopens app, your application calls onResume state. This methods are handled automatically by native android by default. But in case of React-native, i think with implemenation of this method it should work well. so please look at the above references i had provide above.

Comment: Is there anyway this can be handled using react native code and not native android code?

Answer (score 0):

can you make sure you app is live when you press home?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: i mean if you alway show the splash screen when you reopen the app, is there any possible that you app is killed when you hit home?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is not to use splashscreen as a scene. If you use that in such a way it is not splashscreen rather a component. Use the native java code as mentioned in the links below to get your problem solved like charm.

https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-splash-screen

with this there are certain import errors which can be fixed looking at the issues section or check my code in github which contains the perfect use of the splashscreen module.

https://github.com/UjjwalNepal/Dental

Hope this helps.
Thank you